# Were any Jedi officially OKed to marry by the Council?

Tags: star-wars

I know that some Jedi had relationships (include Qui-Gon), and some even married in opposition to Jedi customs and contrary to Council will (that's a stone in your backyard, Mrs Anakin Skywalker!)

But was there ever a case where Jedi Council reversed its position and officially OKed for a Jedi to marry while remaining an active member of the order?

I don't know if the Council existed or had marriage prohibition during Old Republic era, so the scope of the question is 1000BBY-0ABY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was at least one occasion this occured, BUT it was an extremely specific situation, so I'm pretty sure it was a very rare case (if not the only one).

[Ki-Adi-Mundi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ki-Adi-Mundi) was that case.

> **Due to the Cerean's social customs and low birth rate for males**, Mundi was granted an extremely rare exception to be allowed to marry and have children, which was usually strictly forbidden by the Jedi Order as Jedi were not allowed personal attachments. (wording from the Wookieepedia, canon source is *Star Wars: Republic 62: No Man's Land*)

Interestingly enough, he showed that the council was NOT wrong in trusting him:

> Although Mundi was granted the rare exception of being allowed to marry, he was forbidden by the Jedi Code to develop any personal attachments to members of his family. Mundi struggled with this requirement, and despite it demonstrated on multiple occasions that he deeply cared for his family, such as when he fell into despair over the safety of his Sylvn when she was kidnapped. He further showed this attachment by his strong desire to have a son in addition to his daughters.
>
> Nevertheless, Mundi was able to put his service to the Jedi Order ahead of his feelings toward his family, thus demonstrating a large amount of control over his emotions. This was particularly evident when, after his family was killed following the Battle of Cerea, **Mundi was able to remain focused on his Jedi service and overcome his grief during a situation in which other Jedi would risk falling to the dark side of the Force**. (source: Wookieepedia, primary canon sources: *Star Wars: Republic 3: Prelude to Rebellion, Part 3*,  *Star Wars: Republic 5: Prelude to Rebellion, Part 5*, *The Official Star Wars Fact File 140*)