# Which Jedi had children?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Is Anakin Skywalker the only Jedi to produce children?

Please separate answers into canon film and other sources.

Comment: TIL: "Jo Jo was a Gungan, one of Jar Jar Binks' three children".

Comment: If you can prove Jar Jar was a Jedi that would be more interesting than the original question.  Unfortunately I think concensus is he's not.

Answer (score 6):

Disney Canon:

- Anakin Skywalker => Luke & Leia
- Leia Organa => Ben (unknown last name) aka Kylo Ren. In all fairness, she never became a Jedi that we know outside EU/Legends, so this may not count.

Legends/EU:

Way way way way too many to count. Notable (or just random) examples include:

- A whole bunch of Jedi children in aptly named "Children of the Jedi" book by Barbara Humbly
- Corran Horn was a grandson of a Jedi
- Sharad Hett's son who [became important in EU timeline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Krayt). In all fairness, that was AFTER he resigned from Jedi order officially.
- There was one Jedi who was [explicitly permitted to marry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45513/976) (several wives) and have children because his species was basically going extinct as it was.
- As far as I recall, many students at Luke's Jedi Academy were Jedi descendants. That was one of the way he searched for them.

  - Kam Solusar's father was a Jedi Master
  - Ta'ania's mother was a child of a Jedi Master
  - [Margolis Mingla](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Margolis_Mingla) (Cray Mingla's mother) was a child of a Jedi.
- [Keiran Halcyon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Keiran_Halcyon) (Corran Horn's ancestor from 400 BBY, so well after Old Republic and Jedi new family rules)
- All the main protagonists who were Jedi (Luke+Mara Jade and Leia) had children. Luke and Mara had several generations of descendents, ending with Kor and then Cade Skywalkers.
- Obviously, going back to Old Republic times, Jedi were allowed to marry and have kids, until the rules changed around Great Sith War.

  - The whole [Shan line](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Satele_Shan), ascending to Revan and Bastila Shan
  - [Sunrider](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Andur_Sunrider) line
  - [Diath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dace_Diath) line
  - [Draay family](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Draay_family)

Comment: Was Leia a Jedi in Disney Canon? Or just very force sensitive?

Comment: May be worth explicitly calling out the second and third generations of Skywalkers//Organa-Solos

Comment: @MichaelT - fair enough

Comment: In Disney canon, Leia never became a Jedi. And Kylo Ren's full birth name is Ben Solo.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Is there canon proof it's not Ben Organa? I thought it was not clarified? (and see my clarification for Leia - that's exactly what I said :)

Comment: @DVK - i suppose not yet, though just about every site talking about *SW:TFA* refers to him as Ben Solo. I have seen only 2 sites call him Ben Solo-Organa.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - His name is Ben Thrawn. There, now a site says that's his name. What do you mean you want proof?