# How could Rey be Palpatine's grandchild if her father was not Force-sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Kylo says to Rey, "My mother was the daughter of Vader, your father was the son of the Emperor." But Leia was Force-sensitive, and therefore the Force lineage Vader → Leia → Kylo makes sense.

But Palpatine → Dathan → Rey, not so much. Dathan wasn't Force-sensitive.

Is there some explanation for this?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your thinking. Why do you see this as a problem? Are you assuming that every other Jedi (or Sith) in history was the child of at least one Force-sensitive parent? If so, what makes you believe that?

Comment: Well, the surprising thing is that in a universe where Force sensitivity is supposed to be largely the result of the will of the Force or the midichlorians choosing regardless of parentage—thus why the Jedi were always taking random children to be raised at the Temple—the Skywalkers and the Palpatines inherit anything at all. The Force is strong with their bloodline, I guess.

Comment: It skips a generation sometimes.

Comment: Some equivalent of "recessive genes" with midichlorians?

Comment: 'Recessive genes' is closer to the kind of answer I was looking for. It cannot skip generations, otherwise it wouldn't be a force lineage in the Vader>Leia>Kylo sense, that is to say the way it is presented in the film. Did Kylo know Rey's father was a non-FS clone? I mean, maybe Palpatine didn't tell him that. As for the midichlorians, there's an interesting fact about them: according to Lucas, they're based on mitochondria, and you obtain them through your mother. Through a womb. But Rey's father was never inside a womb...

Answer (score 3):

In Canon there are only four characters who are descendants of force sensitives but in legends there are more characters.

If you look at this question:
[Which Jedi had children?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112218/which-jedi-had-children)

There are a few characters who are descendants of force sensitives but not force sensitives themselves.